# JBoss AS7 JNDI Datasource lost after republish

Tags: eclipse, datasource, jndi, jboss7.x

im having the next issue since using the new JBoss AS7 with Eclipse Indigo.

After i've made a change in any static content file, like css, html or images and save it, Eclipse republishes it, as it should.

My problem is that after the republish, my JBoss JNDI Datasource simply fails, i need to restart the JBoss server to get it back to work again with the datasource.

The datasource is a simple connection to MS SQL Server 2008, using the sqljdbc4.jar, i copied it to the deployments folder, using the standalone configuration, and i created the datasource using the JBoss AS7 Admin Web Console, so its supposed to be like jboss says it should be.

Anyone can help me with this?

Also, another behavior, if i modify in eclipse a dynamic content like the main index.jsp file, jboss shows like if it republishes it, but i cannot see the changes until i fully restart the server within Eclipse :S

Please! Help!!

Answer (score 1):

Do a 'Full Publish' in Eclipse.  Right click on the your app in the Server tab under the Jboss server.